How to use fused type for type check in .pyx file
I want to change my use to fused type in Factorial class' datatype check, so I should be able to replace (int, float, str, Special_Object) by my_allowed_type.
But I keep getting an error.

How can I avoid the error?
Is it possible to use fused type in .pyx file?
Is it possible to include None type in fused type/variable?

Fused type
ctypedef fused my_allowed_type:
    int
    float
    str
    Special_Object

Original code
cdef class Factorial:

  def __cinit__(self, object value=None):
     cdef Special_Object new_value = Special_Object("0")

      if isinstance(value, Special_Object):
       new_value = deepcopy(value)
     elif isinstance(value, (int, float, str)):  # Replace this with my_allowed_type
       new_value = Special_Object.builder().add(value).build()

     self.thisptr = make_shared[_Factorial](new_value.thisptr)

Preferred code
cdef class Factorial:

  def __cinit__(self, my_allowed_type value=None):
     cdef Special_Object new_value = Special_Object("0")

      if isinstance(value, my_allowed_type):  # I want to change to something along this line.
       new_value = Special_Object.builder().add(value).build()

     self.thisptr = make_shared[_Factorial](new_value.thisptr)

Error

Type is not specialized

